# Flutter: Platformexception when sending pdf as attachment to an email

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, error-handling

when I start my app and call a method that sends an email with a pdf by pressing a button, i get this error message:

```
E/flutter (19899): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(not_available, No email clients found!, null, null)
E/flutter (19899): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
message_codecs.dart:652
E/flutter (19899): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
platform_channel.dart:310
E/flutter (19899): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19899): #2      _HomeScreenState.sendEmailWithPDF
home.dart:104
E/flutter (19899): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19899): #3      _HomeScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>
home.dart:766
E/flutter (19899): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19899):
```

The method that is causing the error:

```
Future<void> sendEmailWithPDF(pw.Document pdf) async {
    print("AnfangSendEmail");
    //final pdfFile = await pdf.save();
    final Directory tempDir = Directory.systemTemp;
    final String pdfPath =
        '${tempDir.path}/Arbeitszeiterfassung_' + user2! + '.pdf';
    /* final pdfFile = await pdf.save(); */
    final Uint8List pdfBytes= await pdf.save();
    final File pdfFile = File(pdfPath);
    await pdfFile.writeAsBytes(pdfBytes);
    print("MitteSendEmail");
    final Email email = Email(
      body: 'Hier ist die PDF mit den Arbeitszeiten',
      subject: 'PDF mit Arbeitszeiten von ' + user2!,
      recipients: ['jurassichd48@gmail.com'],
      attachmentPaths: [pdfPath], 
      isHTML: false,
    );
    print("EndeSendEmail");
    await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
  }
```

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<queries> <intent> <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" /> <data android:scheme="mailto" /> </intent> </queries>
    <application
        android:label="arbeitszeiterfassung"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="flutter_email_sender" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I already looked up same problems of others but the solutions didnt fix my problem. I changed the AndroidManifest.xml, still same error.

Thanks